# Overriding Data based on sub query

Tags: mysql

I have a Rates table that records the rate of a process

```
DateTime                Rate  
2013-11-25 05:00:00     22  
2013-11-25 06:00:00     78  
2013-11-25 07:00:00     33  
2013-11-25 07:10:00     56  
2013-11-25 08:30:00     12
```

and a Downtime table that records time periods where the above data may not be valid

```
StartDateTime                EndDateTime  
2013-11-25 04:59:00          2013-11-25 05:10:00  
2013-11-25 07:00:00          2013-11-25 07:15:00
```

How can I get the following output where any Rate value recorded between any period in the Downtime table is replaced by a fixed value e.g. 50?

```
DateTime                Rate  
2013-11-25 05:00:00     50  
2013-11-25 06:00:00     78  
2013-11-25 07:00:00     50  
2013-11-25 07:10:00     50  
2013-11-25 08:30:00     12
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT r.datetime, if(d.startDatetime IS NULL, r.rate, 50) rate
FROM rates r
LEFT JOIN downtime d
ON r.datetime BETWEEN d.startDatetime AND d.endDatetime
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6e992/1).

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, works like a charm; the if(d.startDatetime IS NULL, r.rate, 50) was what was eluding me. Thanks.